# Andoid studio is very slow

Tags: android-studio

I am using android studio and it is very slow. every change takes long to happen and the UI is very sluggish.

How can I make it faster?

My laptop config is:

- i5 core 6GRam
- Hd4000 graphic card.

I am new to android development. So it is my first use of Android Studio. I'm compare it with Visual Studio.

By saying slow I mean:

1. When I run android studio, it takes around a minute till android studio GUI appears.
2. In GUI, if I want to change any part of application UI, the GUI is very sluggish (for example if I want to scroll down to find a property to change, it takes around 5 sec t scroll the property window).
3. If I want to run an application on an emulator, it takes around 1 minute till it starts running on an emulator.
4. If I click a button on emulator(for example home button), it would takes 4-5 sec to see its effect.

Comment: What exactly is slow? What changes "take ages" and what do you define as an "age"? Have you tried it on another machine? Describe your problem in detail. I assume you are talking about the Android Development Studio. Has this always been like this or did it only just become slow? Describe in detail, be objective and specific.

Answer (score 2):

check this out http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html for emulator help.

As for the GUI taking ages, try 
File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance > check if "animate windows" is selected and deselect it. 
Then go to 
System Settings > Synchronize files on frame activation / deactivation

Comment: On the last step, what should be done when you get there?